# rst2html on full python project

Tags: python, pycharm, docutils

How can I configure `rst2html` to run on a full Python project instead of a single file?

I'm used to epydoc generating my docs, but thinking to use reStructuredText because it's PyCharm default (I know we as well could change PyCharm to epytext)

Answer (score 1):

`rst2html` cannot do that by itself. It's a ridiculously thin wrapper over `docutils.core.publish_cmdline`. Check it's source:

https://github.com/docutils-mirror/docutils/blob/master/tools/rst2html.py

If you want to process several `.rst` files, you could write a short shell script that calls `rst2html` on each file.

Alternatively you can write a Python script. Here is an example:

```
# https://docs.python.org/3/library/pathlib.html
from pathlib import Path

# https://pypi.org/project/docutils/
import docutils.io, docutils.core

def rst2html(source_path):
    # mostly taken from
    # https://github.com/getpelican/pelican/
    pub = docutils.core.Publisher(
        source_class=docutils.io.FileInput,
        destination_class=docutils.io.StringOutput)
    pub.set_components('standalone', 'restructuredtext', 'html')
    pub.process_programmatic_settings(None, None, None)
    pub.set_source(source_path=str(source_path))
    pub.publish()

    html = pub.writer.parts['whole']

    return html

SRC_DIR = Path('.')
DST_DIR = Path('.')

for rst_file in SRC_DIR.iterdir():
    if rst_file.is_file() and rst_file.suffix == '.rst':

        html = rst2html(rst_file)

        with open(DST_DIR / (rst_file.stem + '.html'), 'w') as f:
            f.write(html)
```

A useful reference could be:

http://docutils.sourceforge.net/docs/api/publisher.html